# Let $A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\alpha, \beta>0$. Prove that $(\alpha+\beta)A\subseteq \alpha A + \beta A$

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness

Let $A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\alpha, \beta>0$. Prove that

a) $(\alpha+\beta)A\subseteq \alpha A + \beta A$

b) equality holds in (a) if and only if A is convex.

I have attempted to "pick" a point in the LHS, and see if it ends up in the RHS, using the fact that every sequence has a convergent subsequence definition, to no avail as of yet.

Comment: (a) is much simpler than you think

Answer (score 1):

For $a)$ we do not need that $A$ is compact: Let $x \in ( \alpha+ \beta)A$. Then there is $a \in A$ such that  $x = (\alpha+ \beta)a$. Then:

$$ x= \alpha a+ \beta a \in  \alpha A+ \beta A.$$

Comment: Does this answer OP question?

Answer (score 1):

for the first question

we have $(\alpha  +\beta )a=   \alpha  a+\beta a \in  \alpha  A+\beta A$ for any $a\in A$ that is 
$$ (\alpha  +\beta )A\subset \alpha  A+\beta A $$

> **Defintion** A is convex set if and only if $$ tA+(1-t)A \subset A ~~~0\le t\le 1$$

taking for any $\alpha>0,\beta>0$ $$t = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha +\beta} \Longleftrightarrow  1-t = \frac{\beta}{\alpha +\beta} $$
Thus we get,
$$A~~\text{convex}~~\Longleftrightarrow tA+(1-t)A \subset A ~\\\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{\alpha}{\alpha +\beta} A+ \frac{\beta}{\alpha +\beta} A \subset A \\\Longleftrightarrow   \frac{1}{\alpha +\beta}(\alpha  A+\beta A)\subset A \\\Longleftrightarrow \alpha  A+\beta A \subset (\alpha  +\beta) A $$

that is $$ A~~\text{convex}~~\Longleftrightarrow \alpha  A+\beta A \subset (\alpha  +\beta) A \subset \alpha  A+\beta A \Longleftrightarrow \alpha  A+\beta A = (\alpha  +\beta) A$$